# What is the difference between Complex derivative and Complex differentiability?

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the difference between [Complex derivative](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexDerivative.html) and [Complex differentiability](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexDifferentiable.html)? And if they are different how you define Complex derivative? Is it same as definition of complex differentiability?

Comment: If a function is complex differentiable at a point, then it has a complex derivative at that point....

Comment: Same thing basically. A functions is 'complex differentiable' iff it has a complex derivative (over $\mathbb{C}$). Generally the point is that being differentiable over $\mathbb{C}$ is a lot stronger than being differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, *differentiability* is the property of having a *derivative*. The difference is the same as that between the *inverse* and *invertibility*.

Comment: the question should be of course: 
What is the difference between Complex derivative and Complex differentiable?

Comment: @alvoutila: Apart from the apparent linguistic difference, there is nothing else. Complex derivative exists for a function if and only if it is complex differentiable.